# How to preg_match regex values between dynamic urls in php

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match

I want to preg_match the values between these html tags with php but the url is dynamic in these html elements it is change every time

`<a class='feedlink' target='_blank' href='https://www.hostname.com/itm/1385154?hash=itm24460266c2:g:GRsAAOSwoc9lCywT'>`**This is Value-1**`</a></h4><table border="0" cellpadding="8">`

`<a class='feedlink' target='_blank' href='https://www.hostname.com/itm/1456754?hash=itm44644556c6:g:yty5yh6jk76rt564'>`**This is Value-2**`</a></h4><table border="0" cellpadding="8">`

`<a class='feedlink' target='_blank' href='https://www.hostname.com/itm/1753454?hash=itm53556545h2:g:gdj89900lldsd46h'>`**This is Value-3**`</a></h4><table border="0" cellpadding="8">`

Continue....!

**Note: above html content is stored in a php variable for example like $myfeed**

I want to preg_match these values from above html elements, values are also change every time

**This is Value-1**

**This is Value-2**

**This is Value-3**

Comment: Do not use regex at all! Parse the HTML. https://3v4l.org/n6S9C

Comment: it not solve my issue becuase there are also other links in the page so your solution will Parse all links

Comment: It will. You can filter for attributes. https://3v4l.org/fD3K2 This will only select such having class=feedlink

Comment: Ok but if the above html elements are stored in a php variable, i mean the whole html in variable then how to extract those values from that specific html elements? i think that's why i asked for preg_match, for example like $myfeed contain all above html elements then how i can extract those values?

Comment: ?? Look at the code. The whole HTML is in the $html variable. I just gave you an example on how you can extract the tag values. What is your question?!